# Xamarin Android Websview UserAgentString not setting

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, user-agent

I am trying to set User agent string in my web view in Xamarin Android app but it added only once and not adding after that. I am calling this code in OnCreate event

```
        webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        webView.ClearCache(true);
        webView.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
        webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(false);
        //webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        //webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
        //string dbPath = Application.Context.GetDir("database", FileCreationMode.Private).Path;

        //webView.Settings.DatabasePath = dbPath;
        //webView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        //webView.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.UserAgentString += " AndroidAPP";

        webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));

        webView.LoadUrl(myurl);
```

I am getting fowwling agent string in website logs

User agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280 Build/NMF26Q; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.100 Mobile Safari/537.36

only one time I got this string

User agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280 Build/NMF26Q; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.100 Mobile Safari/537.36 **AndroidAPP**

What I need to do?

Comment: In which situation you could see the "AndroidAPP" ?

Comment: It happened only once but not happening again, can't say exactly. Just wondering the way I am modifying user agent, is this the correct way or any other way is also available?